# codenameone List Hortizontal scrolling

Tags: java, codenameone

How can I implement a horizontal scroll bar in a list in codenameone?
There seems to be no scrollpane?

I have tried some other ways around but it seems like I'll really need a horizontal scroll in the list. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List in Codename One can be either horizontal or vertical and doesn't provide the ability to side scroll. This is an uncommon pattern in mobile devices and if you need it you should probably rethink your UI design.

Comment: Yeah, it's only a problem on small devices because some item names are rather long. But I'll try to redesign it, thanks man :)

Comment: @Shai Almog please do you think you could help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730176/j2me-how-to-parse-a-byte-array-into-xml-and-then-read-and-display-specific-data